# How to access instance variable in static companion object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make utils for performing network operations in `kotlin`. I have below code where the primary constructor is taking `Command` and `Context`.

I am unable to access command variable in `command.execute(JSONObject(jsonObj))`, getting below error. I am not sure what is causing an issue?

> Unresolved reference: command

```
class AsyncService(val command: Command, val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        fun doGet(request: String) {
            doAsync {
                val jsonObj = java.net.URL(request).readText()
                command.execute(JSONObject(jsonObj))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A companion object is not part of an instance of a class.
You can't access members from a companion object, just like in Java you can't access members from a static method.

Instead, don't use a companion object:

```
class AsyncService(val command: Command, val context: Context) {

    fun doGet(request: String) {
        doAsync {
            val jsonObj = java.net.URL(request).readText()
            command.execute(JSONObject(jsonObj))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should pass arguments directly to your companion object function:

```
class AsyncService {

    companion object {
        fun doGet(command: Command, context: Context, request: String) {
            doAsync {
                val jsonObj = java.net.URL(request).readText()
                command.execute(JSONObject(jsonObj))
            }
        }
    }
}
```